# Android- Is recycler view item has focus

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Is there any way by which I could get to know items in Recycler view are focused or not?

Comment: For that you need to add one boolean param in your model for that recyclerview to set it enabled or disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if android framework provides this information, but you can add a field as `false` to your list model and change it in your adapter when your view ( edittext etc ) gains focus.